# http request handling in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

```
app.delete('/deletebyid/:id',function(req,res){
Users.forEach(function(user){
    if(user.id == req.params.id)
    {
        const index = Users.findIndex(x => x.id == req.params.Id);
        /*second parameter is the number of objects i need to delete
        * arrayName.splice(index,number of objects)*/
        Users.splice(index,1);
        res.status(200).send(Users[index]);
    }
});
res.status(500).send({message:"Invalid User"});
```

According to the code above, first I check whether I am deleting the correct user by comparing user id from my "User" array and the id which I have entered in my URI at first if condition.

What is the use of checking that condition again
at this line?

```
const index = Users.findIndex(x => x.id == req.params.Id);
```

Comment: Instead of using `forEach`, you shoud do `const myUser = Users.find(u => u.id == req.params.id); res.send(myUser);`

Answer (score 0):

At this line `user.id == req.params.id`, you are checking if the ***user object*** and the request params are the same

In the below line, you are finding an index of the element in an `Users` array so that it can be removed in the later line

```
const index = Users.findIndex(x => x.id == req.params.Id);
Users.splice(index,1);
```

If the element is not found, index would be -1. Its good to check for that condition as well.
Now what will ***not work*** is `Users[index]`

Lets see an example

```js
const Users = [1, 3, 5,7,9];
const id = 5;
const index = Users.findIndex(x => x == id); // index is 2
Users.splice(index,1);
console.log(Users[index]);// output is 7 and not 5
```